# stored procedures in SQL with result set

Tags: t-sql

EXECUTE the stored procedure - Using EXECUTE command by adding a WITH RESULT SETS statement.

How to write this?

Answer (score 2):

[WITH execute_option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.a
AS
    SELECT Name FROM sys.tables
GO

EXEC dbo.a WITH  RESULT SETS 
(
    (
        Name sysname
    )
)
```